# Spring JPA failing to use second data source

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, datasource

I am having some difficulties trying to use a secondary data source in my Spring Boot application.

In my application class, I define both data sources:

```
@Bean @Primary @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource defaultDataSource() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "db2") @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.db2")
public DataSource secondDataSource() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Setting the default data source this way works, and all entities are associated to the default database with no extra configuration. The problem comes when trying to consume entities that should be associated with the second data source, as Spring thinks these belong as well to the default data source.

I am trying to use the *@Table/schema* attribute with the same value as the *@Bean/name* defined in the application class, but it doesn't work. The error I keep getting is *Table 'db1.mytable' doesn't exist*, which is wrong since mytable belongs to the database *db2*.

Here is a brief example of such entity:

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "mytable", schema = "db2")
public class MyTable {

  @Id @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "foo", nullable = false)
  private String foo;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The distinction/separation of the underlying database doesnt take place in the entity class, but in the wiring of TransactionManager/SessionFactory. (In your case it sounds like you need two TransactionManagers/SessionFactories, which your code accordingly would operate on...)

Comment: this can help you: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but you want to switch to specific database upon application startup?